# Prohibit ampersand in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

NOT a Rails 3 issue

In a Contact model I have a company_name attribute. For reasons that don't matter to this question, I want to prohibit an ampersand character. We have a lot of clients with ampersands in their company name, and users forget they aren't allowed to use this character.

This isn't an html sanitize issue. I don't care about whitespace or CDATA or anything. The entries in this field are plain text and I don't want an ampersand to be entered in this one field in any way, shape or form.

I assume a validation on the model is the way to go. I have tried validates_exclusion_of. I have tried validates_format_of. No success. I'm unsophisticated when it comes to regex, so I might be doing things very wrong. But the bottom line is - I need to prevent a user from entering that "&" character in the company_name field.

Thanks a million.

Steve

Comment: The reasons may not matter, but that won't stop us from being extremely curious as to why you'd force companies to not enter their true name in the name field.

Comment: it's a long story. There is a Company model which we don't (yet) interact with directly, but there is a relationship where Company has_many contacts. When we create a contact, I do a find_or_create_by_name to either create the association with an existing Company or create a new Company record if one doesn't exist. Putting the "&" into the database doesn't present any problems here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am also doing an autocomplete for that field, and the javascript that performs this action apparently encodes the "&" into "&amp;" when it fetches the record, thus creating a NEW Company the next time we add a contact and making a mess of things.
I can't figure out how to modify the foolish autocomplete script, so the next best things was to avoid inserting that character in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :company_name, :with => /\A[^&]*\Z/
```

But probably you could just remove ampersands before saving record:

```
before_save :strip_ampersands

def strip_ampersands
  company_name.gsub!("&", "")
end
```

Comment: Voyta - thank you SO much. Actually the before_save option is perfect because I can use that to transparently swap the ampersand for the word "and." Perfect!